# How to redirect aws vpn login success url to custom domain url

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, okta, aws-vpn

**Trying to setup the aws vpn client endpoint with Okta saml authentication. After the VPN client connection getting the default success page(http://127.0.0.1:35001/). but my requirement is redirect to custom domain url(for example abc.com) instead of http://127.0.0.1:35001/**

**Thanks in advance for the help**

Comment: On Okta there is the "Default Relay State" parameter which is used for redirection post successful SAML login. Set the URL as per your requirement here and test to see if that helps in the redirection.

Per Okta documentation: 
Default Relay State: the URL that users will be directed to after a successful authentication through SAML.